# dataloader PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file, but the image is not corrupt

Tags: pytorch, python-imaging-library, dataloader

When trying to iterate through dataloader, it returns 'PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file'.

Searched for similar question and answers tend to points to corrupted image. However those images can be opened with Image.open() and file extension are all jpg.

What's a simple way to handle this?

Comment: Did you find the problem? I have the same problem after some epochs, so images are not corrupted.